# Managing bluetooth connection Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, android-bluetooth

I am currently trying to connect a bluetooth HC-05 module with Android so that it sends bytes through the module to the Android device.  I robbed some code almost directly from the android developer page here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ManagingAConnection

Here is the Main.  The problem that I'm having is that the mhandler is not receiving the MESSAGE_READ case and which means I am not receiving the data from my module.  I was wondering what I need to do to get data to be sent up to run that MESSAGE_READ case?  So far the program pairs the device and sends "successfully connected" to my arduino.

Here is also a previously asked question by someone who probably worded it better than me that wasn't answered so I guess I'm not the only one.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088856/no-data-buffered-from-bluetooth-module

The difference I see in our code mainly is that he did start() his connectedThread(). Thanks for helping!

```
public class Main_Activity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

ListView listView;
BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
Set<BluetoothDevice> devicesArray;
ArrayList<String> pairedDevices;
ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices;
public static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
protected static final int SUCCESS_CONNECT = 0;
protected static final int MESSAGE_READ = 1;
IntentFilter filter;
BroadcastReceiver receiver;
String tag = "debugging";
Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(tag, "in handler");
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch(msg.what){
        case SUCCESS_CONNECT:
            // DO something
            ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CONNECT", 0).show();
            String s = "successfully connected";
            connectedThread.write(s.getBytes());                
            Log.i(tag, "connected");

            break;
        case MESSAGE_READ:
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[])msg.obj;
            String string = new String(readBuf);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, 0).show();              
            break;  

        }
    }

};
```

Here is the code that is supposed to send the handler up:

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
            // because mmSocket is final
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice = device;
            Log.i(tag, "construct");
            // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                Log.i(tag, "get socket failed");

            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Log.i(tag, "connect - run");
            try {
                // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
                // until it succeeds or throws an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
                Log.i(tag, "connect - succeeded");
            } catch (IOException connectException) {    Log.i(tag, "connect failed");
                // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) { }
                return;
            }

            // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)

            mHandler.obtainMessage(SUCCESS_CONNECT, mmSocket).sendToTarget();
        }



        /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer;  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {


                try {

                    // Read from the InputStream
                    buffer = new byte[1024];
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your use of threads is simply wrong.

Creating a thread object does not start a physical thread!

Hence placing, as you have done, a potentially slow socket creator function in
the thread object's constructor is again wrong.

And, since you have not start()-ed your thread the socket connect() never gets called!

Please try something along these lines:

```
class ConnectThread extends Thread {

     public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            // nothing long running here!
     }

     public void run() {
         device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);

         // followed by connect() etc.
     }
}
```

Remember to activate the thread by calling

```
  connectedThread.start();
```

Else nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having similar problem with handler. it was long time ago, so I do not remember every details, but it was related to mHandler.sendToTarget. I think there is a mHandler.dispatchMessage method (or smoething like that - i am not on my programing pc so i can't verify this right now). 
You should give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the string "successfully connected" is indeed receiving to arduino? The code snippet do not bring out the write method of  connected thread. Refer bluetoothchat source code available in android sdk.

Couple of areas for you to look for:

1) The connect Thread is not closed before staring connected thread.

2) Definition of constants SUCCESS_CONNECT & MESSAGE_READ. They are private but being accessed from a different class. In bluetoothchat source they are defined as public.

In addition, while referring these constants from a different class we need to refer the class where they are defined, i.e. refer them as shown below:

```
Main_Activity.SUCCESS_CONNECT 
Main_Activity.MESSAGE_READ.
```